# $\prod_{a\in\mathbb{C}}(z-a)\equiv 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, polynomials

We know that, for $1\leq n<\infty$, the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$f(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-a_i),$$

where $a_i\in \mathbb{C}$ for all $i$, is a polynomial which has the $a_i$'s as zeros.

Now, does this expression

$$\prod_{a\in\mathbb{C}}(z-a),$$

as a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, makes sense? If it does make sense, is it identically zero, once every $a\in\mathbb{C}$ is a zero of it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Sums and products over uncountable sets never make sense. How would you define what that product means?

Comment: You would need to define what you mean by an uncountable product.

Comment: Doing uncountable sums and products is not a trivial matter. In fact, one computes infinite products by converting to infinite sums via exponentials. In the real case, there are serious issues regarding uncountable sums. What you find is that for it to be absolutely summable, you need that all but countably many of the terms are nonzero. I suspect something similar happens here.

Comment: @copper.hat I see... Do you suggest something to define it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Especially with complex numbers.